# I Need Create SQL Function To Get The Name When Pass The Id and Table name

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getName](@Id int,@Table_Name sysname,@col_name nvarchar(30),@col_condition)
RETURNS nvarchar(400)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @r nvarchar(250)
    DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(4000)
    SET @DynamicSQL = N'SELECT '+@sl_col+' FROM ' + @Table_Name +' WHERE     @col_condition='+ @id
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
   set @r=EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
    RETURN @r
END
```

Exam:

```
SELECT Emp_Name FROM Emp WHERE emp_id=1
```

Comment: and what's the error?

Comment: where is `@sl_col` get declared?

Comment: also, if you are using `sp_executesql`, you do not need to put the dynamic parameter part out of the query string, looks like you are using the mixture of `exec(dynamic sql)` and `exec sp_executesql(dynamic sql)`

Comment: sorry its col_name

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use dynamic sql in user defined functions. You can change your function to a stored procedure, but I would suggest re-think this entire approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getName]
(@id int,@Table_Name sysname,@col_name nvarchar(30),@col_condition) 

RETURNS nvarchar(400) 

AS BEGIN 

DELCARE @r varchar(50)
DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(4000) 

SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT @r = ' + @col_name + ' FROM ' + @Table_Name + ' WHERE ' + @col_condition + ' = ' + @id

EXECUTE (@DynamicSQL)

RETURN @r 

END
```

Comment: thanx  but not work 
errors
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure getName, Line 15
Must declare the scalar variable "@r".

Comment: @MohamedAL-Hlwany , check again, my bad I forgot to declare `@r`